# tkinter hide all the widget and show other when CTkSegmentedButton is clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, events, customtkinter

hello I am looking for a way to hide the buttons and show different one based on `CTkSegmentedButton`, which is placed on top of them as showing in image
[software image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bICYm.png)

the code for the application is written down below:

```
from customtkinter import *
from CTkMenuBar import *
from CTkXYFrame import *

set_appearance_mode("dark")

root = CTk()
root.title("Demo")
root.geometry("550x550")
root.minsize(550,550)

# Menu
menu = CTkMenuBar(master = root,bg_color = "#506c94")
menu.add_cascade("Edit")

# Tabs Buttons
def clicked_list(values):
    pass

mytabs = ["Search", "Downoads", "Settings"]
segemented_button = CTkSegmentedButton(master=root,
                                       values= mytabs,
                                       selected_color="#506c94",
                                       selected_hover_color="#728bad",
                                       height= 35,
                                       command=clicked_list)

segemented_button.pack(side="top", padx=5, pady=5, fill=X)
segemented_button.set("Search")

# Download Frame
download_frame = CTkFrame(master = root)
download_frame.pack(side="top", fill = X, padx = 5, pady = 5)

# Download Entry
link_entry = CTkEntry(master = download_frame, placeholder_text="CTkentry")
link_entry.pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=True)

# Download Button
link_button = CTkButton(master = download_frame)
link_button.pack(side="left", padx=3)

# Videos Frame
videos_frame = CTkFrame(master = root)
videos_frame.pack(side="top", expand="True", fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)

# Video 
videos_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
videos_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

scrollable = CTkScrollableFrame(master=videos_frame)
scrollable.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="nesw")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've even attempted to solve the problem What part of the problem do you need help with? Methods for hiding widgets are documented.

Comment: @BryanOakley best way to hide widget and show other through the three button in top of the frame

Comment: Why don't you just use `CTkTabview`?

Comment: @acw1668 want be looking good and it is tiny compare to seg button

Comment: Actually `CTkTabview` uses `CTkSegmentedButton` internally.

Comment: @acw1668 let me check and come back to you